# ASP.NET Bundling and Minification removes unused javascript function declaration

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-authentication, bundling-and-minification

I want to implement the Google Login Button from here: [Google Login](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)

This example uses a JS Function to be called by an event from the API-Script. But my Bundling and Minification which I am also using is removing this "at runtime unused function" `onSignIn`. Because of this my Google-Auth is not working correctly.

Here is my Script-Implementation:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/StartManagerJS").Include(StartManagerJS));
```

Does this Minification supports a option to not remove unused JS-Functions?

Comment: What minification library are you using?

Comment: @ariel I am using the build-in Bundling provided by BundleConfig in my Project